# I deleted all permissions from drop off library

Tags: drop-off-library

I was trying to delete the drop off library from my libraries and ended up deleting permissions including my own.  Now I can't add documents to any of my libraries. I can't get the drop off library back because I deleted everybody's permissions. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

A site collection administrator will be able to re-permission you to the library. This may well be a system/farm account, if you yourself are the administrator.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has a fail-safe for that. 
The person who is deleting the permissions (even if they delete all permissions), will be automatically assigned permissions to the item/list/library.

So even if your Drop Off Library permissions look like that:
[image]

you should be able to access it and restore permission inheritance (and through that default permissions from the site level).

Comment: That isn't always the case. I've had countless end users with Full Control access remove all permissions from libraries and cannot recover. It takes someone with site collection admin privileges to go in and reset inheritance.